# Jump to cell using dropdown list data validation

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a data validation/dropdown list to jump to a specific cell.

I have a large spreadsheet that I need to navigate around, and it is client facing. I'd love to have a dropdown list based off a data validation that could jump to a specific cell so that navigation is a little more straightforward.

I know you can type do "help/go to range" and jump to a specific cell,

But I'm hoping to create a dropdown menu that isn't hyperlink based. Something that says the content of the cell not just its name.

For instance, I want to jump to cell A9, but would like it to say the text of B9 which in this example is "shot001_001"

So the data validation would be a list of Shot_001_001, Shot_001_002, Shot_001_003 etc. (names will change later) But the function would be the same as "go to range"

Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible by using on edit trigger from Google Apps Script.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm LOUSY at coding! I get the very basics, and can sort of cobble stuff together, but I need more help than that for this one. THANK YOU!

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to Jump to Column Based off of Cell Value](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143431/88163)